# Flutter App not building (Gradle Problem) | Stuck at assembleDebug

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

My flutter apps normally build with the old machine I was using but as I changed to a new machine by mounting the old HDD on the new machine it gives an error while building. The error is linked with Gradle for sure but I can't depict what exactly it is saying. I have ran many commands but it still keeps consoling errors.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO KD7h in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**`gradle-wrapper-properties`**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

**`build.gradle`**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: currently it displays the error within seconds of trying to run the app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem revolves around gradle. Flutter doctor is consoling no issue but still the app is not building. This happened after I changed to a new machine

Answer (score 0):

You have a corrupt file that gradle downloaded. You can run `android/gradlew cleanBuildCache` to clean Gradle's cache and then retry so gradle downloads the new dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

App has built. The problem was based on Gradle which I had to delete the file in C:\Users\USERNAME.gradle\wrapper\dists and download another one from https://services.gradle.org/distributions and unzip it into the folder for my case it was gradle-6.7-all. I rebuilt it with good internet connection.